# confusing case behavior with a java static int

Tags: clojure

I'm confused...[this static value](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.awt.image.BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR) is equal to 5

```
user> java.awt.image.BufferedImage/TYPE_3BYTE_BGR
5
```

and a case statement should work like this

```
user> (case 5
        5 "yes"
        "huh?")
"yes"
```

but why does it work like this?  Why doesn't it match?

```
user> (case java.awt.image.BufferedImage/TYPE_3BYTE_BGR
            java.awt.image.BufferedImage/TYPE_3BYTE_BGR "yes"
            "huh?")
"huh?"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `test-constant`s in a `case` expression are not evaluated. So your statement is testing whether the number `5` is the same as the symbol `java.awt.image.BufferedImage/TYPE_3BYTE_BGR`. Since they aren't, it falls through to the default clause.

Comment: Thank you.  That seems to explain things.  I suppose I need to use cond.  Unless you happen to know a way to avoid that extra bit of syntax...

Comment: Nope, `cond` is the way to go.

Comment: you can use a macro expansion to evaluate the symbols into constants at compile time if you really wanted.... probably not worth it but can be useful if this is a syntax you are going to use a lot.